# Sort data within a subquery with another subquery?

Tags: t-sql, group-by, subquery, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort the OUN.note column by using the OUN.outcomeKey, since 
 the way it it is working right now is putting the notes in the wrong order (sorting alphabetically). Any idea on how to go about this? I've been trying to sort the data using another sub-query within, but I haven't had much luck (I don't have a plethora of experience).

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OC.outcomeKey [Outcome Key], OC.outcome [Result],
STUFF((SELECT ','+' '+ OUN.note
FROM
Outcome AS OUT
JOIN OutcomeNote AS OUN
ON OUT.outcomeKey = OUN.outcomeKey
WHERE OUN.outcomeKey = OC.outcomeKey
GROUP BY OUN.note
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') [Outcome Note]
FROM Outcome AS OC
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! Also, please let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: have a look at the [order by clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace the line

```
GROUP BY OUN.note
```

with the line

```
ORDER BY OUN.outcomeKey
```

Also, because the concatenation starts with ', ', you may want to use 1, 2, '' as the additional arguments of the STUFF function. Otherwise, the values in your [Outcome note] column always start with a space.

Edit:

By the way, sorting the notes by outcomeKey in the subquery that generates the values for the [Outcome note] column has no effect... since all the notes in each subquery result will have the same outcomeKey value...

But you may sort on any column you want, of course. Perhaps there are other columns in your OutcomeNotes table that can serve as a useful sorting column of your outcome notes.

If I misunderstood your question, please provide definitions of the Outcome and OutcomeNote tables, together with a demo population of those tables and the desired/expected query result, please.

Edit 2:

Starting with SQL Server 2017, Transact-SQL contains a function called STRING_AGG, which seems to be functionally equivalent (more or less) to MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT function. Using this function, your query would become something like this:

```
SELECT
    OUN.outcomeKey [Outcome Key],
    OC.outcome [Result],
    STRING_AGG(OUN.[Note], ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OUN.outcomeKey) [Outcome Note]
FROM
    Outcome AS OC
    JOIN OutcomeNote AS OUN ON OUN.outcomeKey = OC.outcomeKey
GROUP BY
    OUN.outcomeKey,
    OC.outcome;
```

When using SQL Server 2017 or SQL Azure, this might be a more fitting choice, since it does not only make the query more readable, but it also eliminates the use of (way less efficient) XML-functions in your query.

I too have used the XML-functionality for field concatenation (the way you use it) intensively in the past, but I noticed a considerable drop in performance of my queries (which sometimes contained up to 10 columns with concatenated data). Since then, I tend to go for [recursive common table expressions or scalar UDF with recursion approaches](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) in pre SQL Server 2017 environments.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank You!

Comment: Just added an additional edit to my answer. Maybe that's interesting for you too.